# How to base my Header on the Width of the Window W/O having to repeatedly write the same code

Tags: c#, user-interface, position, cursor

I'm about to pull my hair out. I've been trying to get this to work, but all I can come up with is a console screen that looks like this at the top:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
                                                                                            +
                                                                                            +
                                                                                            +
                                                                                            +
                                                                                            +
Are you ready to play Hangman? yes/no:
```

What I'm trying to do is have Pipes on the short sides of the rectangle at the top (6 rows in length) with '+' on each of the four corners, as well as "----" across the bottom (just as it is currently at the top). I've written this thing 40 different ways but I seem to keep getting the same result. And it seems like it should be easier than writing each stinking line.

So here's my code (I have hidden the unnecessary portions of the code):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Hangman
{
class Program
{

    protected static int firstColumn;
    protected static int firstRow;


     protected static void headerWindow( string border, int posX, int posY)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(firstColumn + posX, firstRow + posY);
            Console.Write(border);

        }
         catch(ArgumentOutOfRangeException error)
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.Write(error.Message);

        }

    }

    //I created a method to perform this, so that I can have the program stay open for either 1) a new game or 2) just to see if I could do it. It works!
    private static void printWord()
    {
        String[] myWordArrays = File.ReadAllLines("WordList.txt");
        Random randomWord = new Random();
        //int lineCount = File.ReadLines("WordList.txt").Count();            
        int activeWord = randomWord.Next(0, myWordArrays.Length);
        string userSelection = "";

        Console.WriteLine("Are you Ready to play Hangman? yes/no: ");

        userSelection = Console.ReadLine();
            if(userSelection == "yes")
            {
                //This runs through the randomly chosen word and prints an underscore in place of each letter - it does work
                foreach(char letter in myWordArrays[activeWord])
                {
                    Console.Write("_ ");

                }

                //This prints to the console "Can you guess what this 'varyingLength' letter word is?" - it does work.
                Console.WriteLine("\n \nCan you guess what this "+ myWordArrays[activeWord].Length +" letter word is?");
                Console.ReadLine();
            } 
            else if(userSelection=="no")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("I'm sorry you feel that way. Press Enter to Exit the program!");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }

    }

    private static void headerFile()
    {
        Console.Clear();
        firstColumn = Console.CursorLeft;
        firstRow = Console.CursorTop;

        int columnNumber = Console.WindowWidth - 1;
        var xcoord = 0;
        var ycoord = 0;

        if(xcoord==0 && ycoord==0)
        {
            headerWindow("+",xcoord,ycoord);
            Console.Write("");
            xcoord++;
        }
     }



    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        headerFile();
        printWord();
    }
}
```

}

I need to point out that if you see multiples of the same thing, it's because I have commented and hid the long lines of code (in case I want to use it later). It was supposed to stay hidden, but apparently Ctrl+A,C copies even the collapsed text in the IDE.

Comment: If you copied all the unnecessary code why can't you just delete it before you click "Post"? Also, can you give an example of what you end goal would look like?

Comment: Because the formatting on this site is such that it resets all the 'spaces' I had to add to the code in order to keep you guys from having to scroll constantly for the important things. And besides that, having that code there doesn't "hurt," it just doesn't help. lol. 

As for an example - it has been answered by Kail - and thank goodness. lol. :) Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code out, I think it does what you need:

```
        for(int i = 0; i < columnNumber; i++) // Loop across long length
        {
            headerWindow("-", i, 0); // Top line
            headerWindow("-", i, 6); // Bottom line
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) // Loop across short length
        {
            headerWindow("|", 0, i); // Left side
            headerWindow("|", columnNumber, i); // Right side
        }
        // Draw over corners with "+"
        headerWindow("+", 0, 0);
        headerWindow("+", 0, 6);
        headerWindow("+", columnNumber, 0);
        headerWindow("+", columnNumber, 6);
```

Output:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                              |
|                                                                              |
|                                                                              |
|                                                                              |
|                                                                              |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

It is intended to go in `headerFile()`. Also you should replace 6 with a constant called `HEADER_HEIGHT` or something similar for easy modification and readability.

Comment: Oh my goodness. Talk about me making it much harder than it needed to be. LOL. So when you added the //draw over corners - it will automatically write over whatever is in there automatically? That's amazing, sir. Thank you so very much. This is exactly what I needed. :)